# Run javascript on multiple selected checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Hello I am currently writing a web application that calculates a number based on what a user has checked.

You can see it [here](https://kantelabs.github.io/PokemonGo-Calc/index.html).

If you go to the link you can see that a person will check a checkbox first and enter a value from the dropdown and type 2 values to get an output.

What I need help with is being able to calculate the value for more than one checkbox at a time.

Right now I can only calculate the value for a `checkbox` one at a time even if multiple are selected. So basically I need help try to figure how to calculate for more than one `checkbox` at a time.

I was using an `if` statement inside my javascript file but thats not giving me the result that I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove else if statements, change for IF only. But I have to say that's solution its not that scalable, and for a big application could turns into a nightmare.

I recommend you try to use **$("input:checked").each(function() {});** if you dont want to store it and just show the values on the client to avoid further problems and bad code. With your line of thought, you'll need everytime make copy and paste those IF's everytime you want to implement new form labels.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    function check(){
        if($('#checkbox1').is(':checked')){
            var pokemonCount = parseInt($("#pokecount1").val());
            var candyCount = parseInt($("#candycount1").val());
            var reqCandy  =  parseInt($("#dropdown1 :selected").val());
            var evolveAmount = 0;

            evolveAmount =  Math.floor(((candyCount + pokemonCount) - 1) / (reqCandy));
            $("#p1").html(evolveAmount);
            }
        if($('#checkbox2').is(':checked')){
            var pokemonCount2 = parseInt($("#pokecount2").val());
            var candyCount2 = parseInt($("#candycount2").val());
            var reqCandy2  =  parseInt($("#dropdown2 :selected").val());
            var evolveAmount2 = 0;

            evolveAmount2 = Math.floor(((candyCount2 + pokemonCount2) - 1) / (reqCandy2));
            $("#p2").html(evolveAmount2);
            }
       if ($('#checkbox3').is(':checked')){
            var pokemonCount3 = parseInt($("#pokecount3").val());
            var candyCount3 = parseInt($("#candycount3").val());
            var reqCandy3  =  parseInt($("#dropdown3 :selected").val());
            var evolveAmount3 = 0;

            evolveAmount3 = Math.floor(((candyCount3 + pokemonCount3) - 1) / (reqCandy3));
            $("#p3").html(evolveAmount3);
            }
        }
    $("#compute").click(function(){
        check()
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at this. I was planning only having three checkboxes open, but if I do want to scale up i'll use the function that you recommended. Would you consider my application as something big, that shouldn't be client side? And last question if you can, can you make a mockup of the function that you recommended?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove Else if to if only

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
function check(){
    if($('#checkbox1').is(':checked')){
        var pokemonCount = parseInt($("#pokecount1").val());
        var candyCount = parseInt($("#candycount1").val());
        var reqCandy  =  parseInt($("#dropdown1 :selected").val());
        var evolveAmount = 0;

        evolveAmount =  Math.floor(((candyCount + pokemonCount) - 1) / (reqCandy));
        $("#p1").html(evolveAmount);
        }
    if($('#checkbox2').is(':checked')){
        var pokemonCount2 = parseInt($("#pokecount2").val());
        var candyCount2 = parseInt($("#candycount2").val());
        var reqCandy2  =  parseInt($("#dropdown2 :selected").val());
        var evolveAmount2 = 0;

        evolveAmount2 = Math.floor(((candyCount2 + pokemonCount2) - 1) / (reqCandy2));
        $("#p2").html(evolveAmount2);
        }
    if ($('#checkbox3').is(':checked')){
        var pokemonCount3 = parseInt($("#pokecount3").val());
        var candyCount3 = parseInt($("#candycount3").val());
        var reqCandy3  =  parseInt($("#dropdown3 :selected").val());
        var evolveAmount3 = 0;

        evolveAmount3 = Math.floor(((candyCount3 + pokemonCount3) - 1) / (reqCandy3));
        $("#p3").html(evolveAmount3);
        }
    }
$("#compute").click(function(){
    check()
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You've used `elseif`, so if the first checkbox is checked then it runs that code and stops. You need a series of if blocks:

```
if(1.isChecked){

}

if(2.isChecked){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `else if` statements in your code, which means that the code of only one of the 3 if statements can be executed. More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp).

You need to replace them with simple `if` statements, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    function check(){
        if($('#checkbox1').is(':checked')){
            var pokemonCount = parseInt($("#pokecount1").val());
            var candyCount = parseInt($("#candycount1").val());
            var reqCandy  =  parseInt($("#dropdown1 :selected").val());
            var evolveAmount = 0;

            evolveAmount =  Math.floor(((candyCount + pokemonCount) - 1) / (reqCandy));
            $("#p1").html(evolveAmount);
            }
        if($('#checkbox2').is(':checked')){
            var pokemonCount2 = parseInt($("#pokecount2").val());
            var candyCount2 = parseInt($("#candycount2").val());
            var reqCandy2  =  parseInt($("#dropdown2 :selected").val());
            var evolveAmount2 = 0;

            evolveAmount2 = Math.floor(((candyCount2 + pokemonCount2) - 1) / (reqCandy2));
            $("#p2").html(evolveAmount2);
            }
        if ($('#checkbox3').is(':checked')){
            var pokemonCount3 = parseInt($("#pokecount3").val());
            var candyCount3 = parseInt($("#candycount3").val());
            var reqCandy3  =  parseInt($("#dropdown3 :selected").val());
            var evolveAmount3 = 0;

            evolveAmount3 = Math.floor(((candyCount3 + pokemonCount3) - 1) / (reqCandy3));
            $("#p3").html(evolveAmount3);
            }
        }
    $("#compute").click(function(){
        check()
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, can't believe it was that simple